# Can a charger not 100% compliant to the USB specification damage my Andoid phone?

Tags: htc-desire, usb, charging

I've bought a [world adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00303YRJY) which can charge USB devices as well.
According to the packing the usb will be powered with more than the 500mA as per USB specification - 1000mA.

Will charging my HTC Desire with this USB/travel adapter damage my phone?

I know that many main boards don't deliver 500mA per socket esp. when another draining device is attached to the neighboring port.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4494/482

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your charger device deliveres the right voltage then you should be safe. The maximum current specification is how much ampare it can deliver before the voltage from your charger goes out of USB voltage specs or blows a fuse.

I don't know how they have constructed the HTC Desire battery chargine part, but I would use your charger. They should have some current limiter for the battery in any case, or you couldn't charge your phone in an ordinary computer USB connection.

Comment: Why -1 on this? Where is the error?

Comment: I don't get the -1 either. As I said above I will check the specifications. I've head a car charger that would not charge the phone. Feeling wise nothing charges to fast as the original charger. I've tested multiple ways of charging (computer usb, car adapter, travel adapter).

Comment: As the phone is desiged to work with USB, it has to take into account that there is some variances in voltage and current from USB ports.
The most important is the voltage, that it doesn't goes up to high. Current sould be of no concern, as long as it can deliver enough.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases your phone will only draw as much power as it needs, and it's OK that the charger can provide more.  However, unless you know that your phone will do this and has other power management safety features, I wouldn't use the charger myself.  I've never had a phone ruined, but I have had batteries ruined by non-official chargers (including one charger that claimed to meet the specifications for my phone).

Comment: I will compare specs of the original charger and the travel adapter to decide.