# Nexus 7 (wifi) 2012 won't charge past 11%

Tags: battery, charging, nexus-7

So I turned on my nexus after maybe a year of inactivity. It was just in my cupboard, mostly because I installed a unstable mod and just wouldn't work. But I was able to fix it. And now it won't go beyond 11% on charging.

Please note that I am not using the original power adapter or the original USB lead to charge it.

Does anyone know how I solve this issue?

Comment: Two possibilities. 1-) Software problem 2-) Dead battery.

Comment: @SarpSTA Can the batteries be replaced?

Comment: Probably. I don't know a lot about Nexus phones. I faced a very similar issue with my old Samsung SIII Mini which change of battery ultimately solved the problem. Don't use non-original charging kit though. Not only is it bad for your device, but it can create **serious risks** such as **exploding due overheating** or **melt battery.**

Comment: @SarpSTA Why should non-original charger be bad for a device?

Comment: @Alex.S Lots of reasons. Quality of used material. Voltage and ampere values. To use original materials is always, always the smarter choice.

Comment: @SarpSTA Well, I assure you that this is just urban legend. How does material quality impact the device that is under charge? Voltage may be a problem, yes (not ampere values!), but not in case if you are using a charger from a known manufacturer (and not some 10-cent charger produced in some chinese cellar that had no qualitiy control at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the suggestions, I am also inclined towards thinking it is a dead battery

Li Ion batteries have a protection circuit that kicks in when the discharge falls below a certain level. It requires certain current to be applied to it before charging can happen. This is called "Boosting". [How to awaken sleeping Li-ion](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/low_voltage_cut_off) explains it and suggests ways

In case you don't have access to such chargers, try switching off the phone and then charging in the hope that it would get enough current to kick start charging. The battery is presumed dead, so leave it like 6 hours on charge in switched off condition

Coming to charger, I agree with what others have said but if you can see the phone charging rate from specs (e.g. gives 1600 mAh current to charge) and your current charger also gives the same or slightly higher, and is 2A , 5V wall charger, it is fine but don't make it a regular practice. In this case, I feel if the current reading is slightly higher it would actually help. This would answer more questions on using chargers meant for a different device [Is my phone liable to explode if I charge it with a charger that came with a different phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/is-my-phone-liable-to-explode-if-i-charge-it-with-a-charger-that-came-with-a-dif)

All the best