# Are Android USB plug-in chargers interchangeable?

Tags: usb, charging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my phone liable to explode if I charge it with a charger that came with a different phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/is-my-phone-liable-to-explode-if-i-charge-it-with-a-charger-that-came-with-a-dif)
>   [Are Android chargers universal in terms of power (Voltage, amperage)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4494/are-android-chargers-universal-in-terms-of-power-voltage-amperage)

I'm developing an app for my job for Android and we're testing on multiple devices.

I know I can charge the phones by plugging them in via USB cables and such but sometimes I may need to charge one or more via plugging them into the wall (or power strip).

Thing is, most of these phones come with a USB cable and a plug adapter to connect the USB cable to. Sometimes the plug adapter doesn't indicate which phone or manufacturer it came with and so it's really easy to get things confused.

What would be really nice is if I could just plug in all of these chargers to a power strip and just plug phones into any of the USB ports. Is this possible? Is it safe? Will I screw anything up if I just plug any phone into any charger?

Comment: I think those should cover this, let me know if not.