# Having trouble powering up my phone with another power source

Tags: battery, charging

I am having a bit of trouble powering my phone I got a Lenovo A7000 plus which is the same as K3 Note version and this phone uses BL243 battery

Here is some information about the battery

Typical Capacity: 3000mAh/11.40Wh
Nominal Voltage: 3.8V
Limited Charge Voltage: 4.35V

and also I have a USB charger 5.0V 1.5A, I used the charger with another K3 Note phone I had, and I used it to power it up (using wires in place of the battery) it looked like it was all fine even after that when I connected the device to my pc it detected the device just fine also the k3 note's screen is damaged soo it won't show anything on it just boots up

so I wanna know is it possible to power my working A7000 plus with that charger using wires instead of the battery without destroying it

Comment: Related or possible duplicate: [Is using chargers of phone not meant for it harmful to the battery?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34573/is-using-chargers-of-phone-not-meant-for-it-harmful-to-the-battery?rq=1)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio But does that apply to A7000 plus/K3 Note?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio also sorry i missed the most important part i am trying to use the charger as in place of the battery using wires